# Trying to change an image in a Label, when a certain Button is clicked

Tags: vb.net, winforms, for-loop

I am creating a game for my Visual Basic class.
So far I have been successful, except for movement on my label grid. I have a 16, 21 Label grid that I am using for the main map.

The X axis is numeric 1-21 and the Y axis is letters A-P. So the upper left Label is named A1 and the bottom right Label is named P21.
The player starts on Label P11 and has an image of an arrow indicating their location.

I also have an up, down, left, right buttons as well. When I press the up Button, I want the image to move itself to O11, or the above Label.
I have a solution, but it is very code extensive, and the up Button alone is 1600+ line of code, which I think is a little excessive.

My variables that I declared and the initial starting Label:

```
Public Letters As New List(Of String)
Public Shared x = 15
Public Shared locationLetter As String
Public Shared locationNumber As Integer = 11 

Public Shared locationPlayer As String
'Put player's ship in starting grid P11
P11.Image = My.Resources.Arrow
```

This code loops through each Label and then finds the one that has the image and then sets its `Image` property to nothing.
It also changes the players location to what it should be, in this case I want the image to go from P11 to O11.

```
Dim nextMove As String

Controls.Find(locationPlayer)

For Each lbl As Label In Controls.OfType(Of Label)
    If lbl.Image IsNot Nothing And x >= 0 Then
        x -= 1
        lbl.Image = Nothing
        locationLetter = Letters.Item(x)
        locationPlayer = CStr(locationLetter & locationNumber)
  
        If lbl.Name = locationPlayer Then
            lbl.Image = My.Resources.Arrow
        End If
    End If
Next
```

This line of code adds the appropriate letters to the Letters list, so that I can call up it to concatenate to find the current position the player should be in:

```
Letters.Add("A") ' 0 position
Letters.Add("B") ' 1 position
Letters.Add("C") ' 2 position
Letters.Add("D") ' 3 position
Letters.Add("E") ' 4 position
Letters.Add("F") ' 5 position
Letters.Add("G") ' 6 position
Letters.Add("H") ' 7 position
Letters.Add("I") ' 8 position
Letters.Add("J") ' 9 position
Letters.Add("K") ' 10 position
Letters.Add("L") ' 11 position
Letters.Add("M") ' 12 position
Letters.Add("N") ' 13 position
Letters.Add("O") ' 14 position
Letters.Add("P") ' 15 position

locationLetter = Letters.Item(15)
```

The code that I have now that is working, but is way excessive is:

```
If P1.Tag = "player" Then
    O1.Tag = "player"
    O1.Image = My.Resources.Arrow
    P1.Tag = ""
    P1.Image = Nothing
    btnDOWN.Enabled = True
    btnLEFT.Enabled = False
ElseIf P2.Tag = "player" Then
   O2.Tag = "player"
    O2.Image = My.Resources.Arrow
    P2.Tag = ""
    P2.Image = Nothing
    btnDOWN.Enabled = True
ElseIf P3.Tag = "player" Then
    O3.Tag = "player"
    O3.Image = My.Resources.Arrow
    P3.Tag = ""
    P3.Image = Nothing
    btnDOWN.Enabled = True
'[...]
End If
```

And so on. I would have to do this for every single Button, so that's 336 blocks x4 Buttons, or roughly 6,720 lines of code to move an image to another box.
My pseudo code for this is:

```
If playerlocation = (some grid number, like P11 for example)
Find the label with the name = to playerlocation and add image to label
i.e.
so if playerlocation = D4
find the label with the name D4 and add the image to the label
```

Comment: `6,720 lines of code to move an image to another box` <= should be a huge red flag that you're doing things very inefficiently. You have 336 squares. So tag them 1 thru 336 and keep track of which the player is on. P11 = 326. When the player moves UP, subtract 21. Moves LEFT, subtract 1. Moves RIGHT, add 1. Moves DOWN, add 21. So in your example, moving UP = 305. So set the images for 326 and 305 and the new player position = 305. If you don't allow wrapping at the borders, then check and don't allow movement. If <=21, they can't move UP etc. It can all be done with probably <100 lines of code

Comment: I like this idea, I will see if this works.I think I will make a loop that checks all the tags of control label and then puts an image at the players location and removes it at another. We will see how this goes. thank you

Answer (score 2):

*Procedural* programming is good!
Some semi-OOP:

A description of what you said you need:

**A Board**
 - it has Dimensions;
 
 - contains a array of, lets say, Cells (which have their own properties);
 - has to allow the movement of a dummy player over its Cells;

**A Player:**
 - It has a position
 - a picture which is the visual expression of its position;
 - an action range: can move and only inside the range of the Cells that
   the Board defines

Building a Board object (of course):

```
Public Class GameBoard

    Private _BoardSize As New Size  'Board size
    Private _CellsArray As BoardCell(,) 'The Cells array
    Private _PlayerDummy As PlayerDummy
    Private _Cells As BoardCell
    Private _cell As BoardCell
    Private _Location As Point
    Private _Container As Control
    Private _PlayerPosition As Point    'Current or default position of the player
    Private _PlayerImage As Image       'Player dummy Image
    Private _Initialized As Boolean = False

    'The BoardSize defaults to 21x15
    Public Sub New()
        Me.New(New Size(0, 0))
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(_size As Size)
        Me._BoardSize = _size
        Me._cell = New BoardCell
        Me._cell.Size = New Size(50, 50)
        Me._PlayerDummy = New PlayerDummy
    End Sub

    Friend Property BoardSize() As Size
        Get
            Return Me._BoardSize
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Size)
            Me._BoardSize = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Friend Property Cell() As BoardCell
        Get
            Return Me._cell
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As BoardCell)
            Me._cell = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Friend ReadOnly Property Cells(_id As Point) As BoardCell
        Get
            Return Me._CellsArray(_id.X, _id.Y)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property Container() As Control
        Get
            Return _Container
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Control)
            _Container = value
            Me._PlayerDummy.Parent = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Location() As Point
        Get
            Return _Location
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Point)
            _Location = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property PlayerPosition() As Point
        Get
            Return Me._PlayerPosition
        End Get
        Set(value As Point)
            If Me._Initialized = True Then
                'If a player position changes, move the dummy image in the new Cell
                If Me._PlayerPosition <> value Then
                    Me._PlayerPosition = value
                    Me._PlayerDummy.Location = Me._CellsArray(value.X, value.Y).Location
                End If
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property PlayerImage() As Image
        Get
            Return Me._PlayerImage
        End Get
        Set(value As Image)
            Me._PlayerImage = New Bitmap(value)
            Me._PlayerDummy.Image = Me.PlayerImage
        End Set
    End Property

    'Dimension (0, 0) is used to show Rows/Columns headers
    Public Sub Initialize(_size As Size)
        Me._BoardSize = _size

        'Defines the number of Cells
        Me._CellsArray = New BoardCell(_size.Width, _size.Height) {}

        'Add Cells classes per dimensions(x, y)
        Dim x As Integer = 0
        While x <= _BoardSize.Width
            Dim y As Integer = 0
            While y <= _BoardSize.Height
                Me._CellsArray(x, y) = CreateBoardCell()
                y += 1
            End While
            x += 1
        End While

        'Paint the Board
        For x = 0 To Me._BoardSize.Width
            For y = 0 To Me._BoardSize.Height
                Dim _position As Point = New Point(x, y)
                If x > 0 And y = 0 Then
                    Me.Cells(_position).Text = x.ToString
                    Me.Cells(_position).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(32, 32, 32)
                    Me.Cells(_position).ForeColor = Color.White
                End If
                If y > 0 And x = 0 Then
                    Me.Cells(_position).Text = Chr(y + 64).ToString
                    Me.Cells(_position).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(32, 32, 32)
                    Me.Cells(_position).ForeColor = Color.White
                End If

                Me.Cells(_position).Location = New Point(Me._Location.X + x * Me.Cell.Size.Width, _
                                                                      Me._Location.Y + y * Me.Cell.Size.Height)
                Me.Cells(_position).Parent = Me.Container
            Next
        Next
        Me.Cells(New Point(0, 0)).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
        Me.Cells(New Point(0, 0)).BackColor = Me.Container.BackColor

        Me._Initialized = True

    End Sub

    Private Function CreateBoardCell() As BoardCell
        Dim _boardcell As BoardCell = New BoardCell
        _boardcell.Size = Me._cell.Size
        _boardcell.BackColor = Me._cell.BackColor
        _boardcell.BorderStyle = Me._cell.BorderStyle
        Me._PlayerDummy.Size = New Size(Me._cell.Size.Width - 1, Me._cell.Size.Height - 1)
        Return _boardcell

    End Function

    'A class defining a Cell object. Inherits from Label.
    'May be a Panel gives more options. Do not use PictureBoxes.
    Public Class BoardCell
        Inherits Label

        Public Sub New()
            'Setup default properties
            Me.AutoSize = False
            Me.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            Me.Visible = True
        End Sub
    End Class

    Friend Class PlayerDummy
        Inherits PictureBox

        Private _Image As Image
        Private _Parent As Control

        Public Sub New()
            Me.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
            Me.BorderStyle = Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D
            Me.Visible = True
        End Sub

        Public Shadows Property Image() As Image
            Get
                Return Me._Image
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Image)
                MyBase.Image = value
                Me._Image = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Shadows Property Parent() As Control
            Get
                Return _Parent
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Control)
                _Parent = value
                MyBase.Parent = value
            End Set
        End Property

    End Class
End Class
```

To create a new Board, instantiate it and definine its properties

```
MyGameBoard = New GameBoard

'Starting position to draw this GameBoard
MyGameBoard.Location = New Point(50, 50)
MyGameBoard.Cell.Size = New Size(50, 50)
MyGameBoard.Cell.BackColor = Color.Wheat
MyGameBoard.Cell.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
'Define the container class (Form, Panel, PictureBox...) that will contain this Board
MyGameBoard.Container = Me

'Assign an Image to the new player object and Position it inside its Board Cell
MyGameBoard.PlayerImage = New Bitmap(My.Resources.horse2)

'Paint the Board giving it desired size
MyGameBoard.Initialize(New Size(10, 10))
```

Now, the Player

```
Public Class Player
    Public Enum Direction   'Enumerates this player allowed directions
        Up = 0              'Maybe it could also move diagonally
        Down
        Left
        Right
    End Enum

    Private _Position As Point              'Player Position
    Private _Boundaries As New Rectangle    'The Boundaries of its movements

    Public Sub New()
        Me.New(Nothing)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(_boundaries As Rectangle)
        Me._Boundaries = New Rectangle(1, 1, _boundaries.Width - 1, _boundaries.Height - 1)
    End Sub


    Public Property Position() As Point
        Get
            Return Me._Position
        End Get
        Set(value As Point)
            'Evaluates whether the position being set violates the 
            'constraints imposed by the Boundaries
            Me._Position.X = If(value.X > Me._Boundaries.Right, Me._Boundaries.Right, value.X)
            Me._Position.X = If(value.X < Me._Boundaries.Left, Me._Boundaries.Left, value.X)
            Me._Position.Y = If(value.Y > Me._Boundaries.Bottom, Me._Boundaries.Bottom, value.Y)
            Me._Position.Y = If(value.Y < Me._Boundaries.Top, Me._Boundaries.Top, value.Y)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Boundaries() As Rectangle
        Get
            Return Me._Boundaries
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Rectangle)
            Me._Boundaries = value
        End Set
    End Property

    'Move of the Player. Evaluates if the requested action violates Boundaries
    Public Function Move(_direction As Direction) As Point
        Select Case _direction
            Case Direction.Up
                Me.Position = New Point(Me.Position.X, If(Me.Position.Y > Me._Boundaries.Top, Me.Position.Y - 1, Me.Position.Y))
                Exit Select
            Case Direction.Down
                Me.Position = New Point(Me.Position.X, If(Me.Position.Y < Me._Boundaries.Bottom, Me.Position.Y + 1, Me.Position.Y))
                Exit Select
            Case Direction.Left
                Me.Position = New Point(If(Me.Position.X > Me._Boundaries.Left, Me.Position.X - 1, Me.Position.X), Me.Position.Y)
                Exit Select
            Case Direction.Right
                Me.Position = New Point(If(Me.Position.X < Me._Boundaries.Right, Me.Position.X + 1, Me.Position.X), Me.Position.Y)
                Exit Select
        End Select
        Return Me._Position
    End Function


End Class
```

Create a new player with movement Boundaries = to the board Size

```
MyPlayer = New Player(New Rectangle(New Point(1, 1), MyGameBoard.BoardSize))
```

Starting position:

```
MyPlayer.Position = New Point(10, 10)
```

Place the Player Dummy

```
MyGameBoard.PlayerPosition = MyPlayer.Position
```

To move it just use the Move method and let the Board know about:

```
MyPlayer.Position = MyPlayer.Move(Player.Direction.Up)
MyGameBoard.PlayerPosition = MyPlayer.Position
```

Place some controls to let the actual human player move the dummy.

[image]

Comment: Wow. I really appreciate your detail and code. I'm also a beginning (< a year of programming experience) programmer. I'm having trouble understanding your code, because for the most part our class hasn't even discussed objects or the like. So while I can imagine what is happening and visualize what should happen (you create a board that has cells and then a player class that can then traverse said game board) I don't really know how to make this work for what I am doing. I did copy and paste it into a test window, but nothing appeared and it is probably because I didn't do it correctly.

Comment: Well, no. Copy & Paste alone won't do. When you create a new Board with `MyGameBoard = New GameBoard(New Size(21, 15))` you have an (almost) fully instantiated object. You still have to "paint" its child object on a surface. A Form maybe. With a catch. I left out the complete definition of the single cell, so at this moment, it doesn't have dimensions or, say, colors. That I left for you. If you need help, ask away.

Comment: @Galacticcore25   Copy & Paste is allowed now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, using labels as fields is a bit weird. However, you could put all the labels into an 2D-Array and remember the player's position. Then, when a movement button is pressed you first check if the player's new position is out of range. if not, you clear the old label and set the new won remembering the new position.

I haven't tested it but something like this should work:

```
Private playfield as Label() = {{P11,P12,P13,...},{P21,P22,P23,...},...}
Private playerX as Integer = 11
Private playerY as Integer = 14


Public Sub btnDOWN_Clicked() Handles btnDOWN.Clicked
    If playerY+1 < 14 Then
        playfield(playerX, playerY).Image = Nothing
        playerY = playerY + 1
        playfield(playerX, playerY).Image = My.Ressources.Arrow

    End If

End Sub
```

Repeat the stuff in btnDown_Clicked for btnUP, btnLEFT and btnRIGHT and change the related variables. Remember to check if your move is valid before you do it or you might get out of range exceptions when walking out of screen.

Comment: Yeah, I know labels was probably not the greatest of choices, but my options were quite limited seeing as that we haven't even gotten to objects or even collection sets yet. I will try and see if this works, though my understanding of 2D-Arrays are limited at best. Thank you